# Updating redundant/denormalized data automatically in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, denormalization

Use a high level of redundant, denormalized data in my DB designs to improve performance.  I'll often store data that would normally need to be joined or calculated. For example, if I have a **User** table and a **Task** table, I would store the *Username* and *UserDisplayName* redundantly in every **Task** record.  Another example of this is storing aggregates, such as storing the *TaskCount* in the **User** table.

- **User**

  - UserID
  - Username
  - UserDisplayName
  - TaskCount
- **Task**

  - TaskID
  - TaskName
  - UserID
  - UserName
  - UserDisplayName

This is great for performance since the app has many more reads than insert, update or delete operations, and since some values like *Username* change rarely. However, the big draw back is that the integrity has to be enforced via application code or triggers. This can be very cumbersome with updates.

My question is can this be done automatically in SQL Server 2005/2010... maybe via a persisted/permanent View.   Would anyone recommend another possibly solution or technology.  I've heard document-based DBs such as CouchDB and MongoDB can handle denormalized data more effectively.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You might want to first try an Indexed View before moving to a NoSQL solution:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187864.aspx

and:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx

Using an Indexed View would allow you to keep your base data in properly normalized tables and maintain data-integrity while giving you the denormalized "view" of that data.  I would not recommend this for highly transactional tables, but you said it was heavier on reads than writes so you might want to see if this works for you.

Based on your two example tables, one option is:

1) Add a column to the User table defined as:

```
TaskCount INT NOT NULL DEFAULT (0)
```

2) Add a Trigger on the Task table defined as:

```
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateUserTaskCount
ON dbo.Task
AFTER INSERT, DELETE
AS

;WITH added AS
(
    SELECT  ins.UserID, COUNT(*) AS [NumTasks]
    FROM    INSERTED ins
    GROUP BY    ins.UserID
)
UPDATE  usr
SET     usr.TaskCount = (usr.TaskCount + added.NumTasks)
FROM    dbo.[User] usr
INNER JOIN  added
        ON  added.UserID = usr.UserID


;WITH removed AS
(
    SELECT  del.UserID, COUNT(*) AS [NumTasks]
    FROM    DELETED del
    GROUP BY    del.UserID
)
UPDATE  usr
SET     usr.TaskCount = (usr.TaskCount - removed.NumTasks)
FROM    dbo.[User] usr
INNER JOIN  removed
        ON  removed.UserID = usr.UserID
GO
```

3) Then do a View that has:

```
SELECT   u.UserID,
         u.Username,
         u.UserDisplayName,
         u.TaskCount,
         t.TaskID,
         t.TaskName
FROM     User u
INNER JOIN   Task t
        ON   t.UserID = u.UserID
```

And then follow the recommendations from the links above (WITH SCHEMABINDING, Unique Clustered Index, etc.) to make it "persisted". While it is inefficient to do an aggregation in a subquery in the SELECT as shown above, this specific case is intended to be denormalized in a situation that has higher reads than writes. So doing the Indexed View will keep the entire structure, including the aggregation, physically stored so each read will not recalculate it.

Now, if a LEFT JOIN is needed if some Users do not have any Tasks, then the Indexed View will not work due to the 5000 restrictions on creating them.  In that case, you can create a real table (UserTask) that is your denormalized structure and have it populated via either a Trigger on just the User Table (assuming you do the Trigger I show above which updates the User Table based on changes in the Task table) or you can skip the TaskCount field in the User Table and just have Triggers on both tables to populate the UserTask table.  In the end, this is basically what an Indexed View does just without you having to write the synchronization Trigger(s).

Comment: Persisted computed columns might also be a good tactic here. With few DML statements being issues they would not need to be updated very often and they're as good as physical records on the table as far as I know.

Comment: @Jeremy: if the aggregation is part of the Indexed View, then it should naturally be stored physically with the rest of the materialized fields so there should be no need for an explicit Persisted Computed Column IF the solution is to use an Indexed View.  However, if not using an Indexed View, then I agree (and you are correct), a Persisted Computed Column is something to look into as it is stored physically as opposed to calculated each time the row is read.

Comment: Computed columns do sounds like a good option, but is it possible to create a computed column calculated from ANOTHER table (User.DisplayName --> Task.UserDisplayName) and have that column automatically updated when the other table/record is updated?

Comment: @Jonathan: No and Yes, and then a However. No, the fields available for a Computer Column need to come from the table itself.  Yes, you "can" create a scalar UDF to accept values (such as the UserID) from the Row and then JOIN to another table to return a single value (such as the DisplayName).  However, doing a UDF in a Computed Column will have performance issues (I am not sure if that can be marked as PERSISTED), and in your case, a simple JOIN between the two tables in a View that has a CLUSTERED Index would solve all of the issues and you would have access to all fields in both tables.

Comment: @srutzky,  In that case it seems a computed column would not work for the purpose of denormalization.  I will try the Indexed View approach.

Comment: @Jonathan: I just added some details to the answer to be more clear. As you can see now, the Computed Column would only help one table (and only if it could be marked as PERSISTED which I don't think it could).

Comment: Yes, it seems to work well in some instances, hover there are some big limitations... mainly no LEFT JOINs and no sub-queries.  This makes it only partially usable to maintain integrity.  When the demoralized data is null-able, you have to resort back to application or trigger code to maintain it.

Comment: @Jonathan: yeah, I see that now. I have updated my answer again to remove the subquery and I replaced it with a column updated via a Trigger. That doesn't solve the LEFT JOIN scenario so I added a final paragraph on doing your own "Indexed View". I hope this helps :).